# Commenting on Q or A, someone comments on mine, Q/A is changed, my comment obsolete, if deleted other comment makes no sense

Tags: discussion, comments

If I comment on a question or answer and my comment gets commented/added to by some other user. Then Q/A gets changed/fixed which makes my comment obsolete - do I delete it (normal if I notice the fix on the Q/A) even if the comment by the other user then loses its context?

I read through the top of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=should+I+delete+comments which consense into "deleting comments after the cause for comment got fixed" is a good thing.

Comment: I would delete it as it is no longer relevant.

Comment: It's a good thing, but not put to much energy into it. I wouldn't return to a question just to check if my comment is obsolete, but if I discover that it is, then I delete it.

Comment: @klutt it's not so much effort to revisit your last X comments from your user page though, I tend to skim them if I know there are a few that will likely go obsolete (or rather: should become obsolete). Something I dislike more than noisy comments is a comment which says "this is not correct, X should be Y" and then then content already contains Y. At least noise you can instantly filter out as irrelevant, obsolete comments are far tougher buggers to disqualify so I put that little bit extra effort.

Comment: @Gimby True, but I think that that responsibility lies on the poster. When someone comment like that my my post, I usually comment "Thanks. Fixed." afterwards.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't have to, but I consider it a good thing to delete such a comment. Often, the other party will also delete their comment after seeing you deleted yours.

If you want to, you can flag the comment with the "no longer needed" reason, so a moderator can clean it up.

Don't worry too much about the other comment not making any sense afterwards.

Comment: Obsolete comments that aren't obviously obsolete when seen in isolation (e.g. "thanks, fixed") are best flagged using a custom reason to justify it (if you don't want the flag to get declined). I'd probably also say the chance of the other party deleting their comment is less "often" and more "once every million years or so".

Comment: @Dukeling YMMV :)

Comment: @Dukeling In my experience, the handling of comment flags on main has pretty well always erred on the side of deletion. That whole second class citizen, ephemeral, temporal thing-a-majigger.